# Binding an element from a ObservableCollection's list into a Treeview Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I'm trying to create a treeview with an ObservableCollection, but I'm having a problem on obtaining the elements from a list in my object. What happens is that I can retrieve the group name, it displays on the list just fine, but then instead of getting the usernames I get a blank space. Here's some code:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeUsers">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GroupName}" >
                        <Grid Margin="1">
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=UserList.Name}"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

In this code, I obtain the users from a list, then separate them into different groups, and return the list to my Viewer.

```
        private Dictionary<string, GroupDTO> _groupsDTO= new Dictionary<string, GroupDTO>();

        _groupsDTO.Add("GENERAL", new GroupDTO("GENERAL"));
        foreach (NetSendUser user in ObtainUserList())
        {
            UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO (user);
            _groupsDTO["GENERAL"].UserList.Add(userDTO );
            if (!_groupsDTO.ContainsKey(user.Area))
                _groupsDTO.Add(user.Area, new GroupDTO(user.Area));
            _groupsDTO[user.Area].UserList.Add(userDTO);
        }

        ObservableCollection<GroupDTO> groups= new ObservableCollection<GroupDTO>(_groupDTO.Values.ToArray());
treeUsers.ItemsSource = groups;
```

And here's my GroupDTO:

```
public class GroupDTO: ObjectDTO
    {
        internal GroupDTO(string name)
            : base()
        {
            _groupName = name;
        }

        private string _groupName = default(string);
        public string GroupName
        {
            get { return _groupName ; }
            set
            {
                _groupName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<UserDTO> _userList= new ObservableCollection<UserDTO>();
        public ObservableCollection<FuncionarioDTO> UserList
        {
            get { return _userList; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not even sure how your application is working at all. You are binding GroupName (property of type string) to an ItemsSource (which requires collection). And then you are trying to bind to UserList.Name, but it is a collection of items, it doesn't expose Name property, User does. Here is a simplified working example.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestBench.TreeSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfTestBench="clr-namespace:WpfTestBench"
    Title="Tree sample" Height="300" Width="300">
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="wpfTestBench:Group" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="wpfTestBench:User">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Username}" />    
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfTestBench
{
    public partial class TreeSample
    {
        public TreeSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new Context();
        }
    }

    public class Context
    {
        public Context()
        {
            Groups = new List<Group>();

            var mainGroup = new Group 
            {
                Name = "Main", 
                Users = new List<User> { new User("John"), new User("Bill") } 
            };

            var secondaryGroup = new Group
            {
                Name = "Secondary",
                Users = new List<User> { new User("Tom"), new User("Phil") }
            };

            Groups.Add(mainGroup);
            Groups.Add(secondaryGroup);
        }

        public IList<Group> Groups { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User(string name)
        {
            Username = name;
        }

        public string Username { get; private set; }
    }    
}
```

Execution result:

[image: Working sample]

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to mention that I was binding my ItemsSource with that "ObservableCollection<GroupDTO> groups= new ObservableCollection<GroupDTO>(_groupDTO.Values.ToArray());". But my main problem is binding the usernames from my GroupDTO's UserList.

Comment: You are using this code for groups binding: <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GroupName}">. It is completely incorrect. And then there is the following bizarre line: <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=UserList.Name}" />. ObservableCollection doesn't expose a property called Name.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that was bizarre, but Username wasn't working for me, that's why I tried that crazy stuff. And you know what was the problem? After reviewing my code again, while checking yours, I found out that I had a UserNane property instead of UserName. And i've been about this problem for days and researching about TreeViews. But thanks for the light!

Comment: +1 for this `I'm not even sure how your application is working at all`